# What is PARQUET_READ_PARALLELISM?

Tags: parquet

When I run my jobs I see:
`parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader: Initiating action with parallelism: 5`

It is by default set to 5 but what is it? and how can I used it to get better performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it defaults to 5.

The configuration parameter's name is `parquet.metadata.read.parallelism`. It affects only in how many threads metainformation about `Parquet` files is read.

I believe it does not affect performance much as it's only related to reading of metadata, not the data itself.

Comment: Is it possible to disable it or set it to one thread like this? 
sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration().setInt("parquet.metadata.read.parallelism", 1)

Comment: You should be able to set it. Might be better to set it when you submit a job.
Like: `spark-submit --conf parquet.metadata.‌​read.parallelism=1`